# Speed up one step NUTS within custome sampler

Tags: python, tensorflow, mcmc

Bsically, I'd like to use NUTS to sample my 1 of my parameters. Here, I use the tensorflow implementation, but the problem is that it is too painful to run even one iteration. Could anyone help me speed it up?

Some pseudo code:

```
for gg in range(1,iter_num):
    # 1. sample parameters except "r" by my own sampler

    # 2. sample parameter "r" by NUTS
    # very SLOW...

    target_lpdf = lambda r: log_pdf(r, other_param_prev)
    nuts = tfp.mcmc.NoUTurnSampler(target_log_prob_fn = target_lpdf,
                                       step_size = tf.cast(.1, tf.float32))
    state = tfp.mcmc.sample_chain(num_results=1,
                                      current_state = tf.cast(r_trace[gg-1], tf.float32),
                                      kernel=nuts)
    r_trace[gg] = np.array(state.all_states, dtype = 'float64')
```